# http to https redirect on openshift rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, openshift

I want my rails 4.0 app on Openshift Online to serve content only over https. 
There is a [guide](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1044-how-to-redirect-traffic-to-https) which tells to use a .htaccess in the web-root:

```
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https  
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I followed the guide and put a .htaccess file with the directive in my app-root/repo directory on the openshift cartridge, but nothing happens. The guide talks about a web-root dir. What is the web-root directory of a rails app, or what is a web-root directory on openshift? And is there another way to establish http to https redirect for rails on openshift?

Comment: I have used this instruction: https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https but received no positive results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a similar situation as you (but wanting to redirect depending on the `Accept-Language` http header), and could not find the place where to put the .htaccess on an OpenShift ruby cartridge.

#### Tentative with .htaccess

I tried to put the .htaccess file in the `app-root/repo`, `app-root/runtime`, `app-root/data`, the `~/ruby/` directories with no success..

So I ended up doing the redirections from the rails app

#### A solution for your case through Rails

If you want to enforce SSL for all your application you can simply set `config.force_ssl = true` in your `config/application.rb` file. Another common use case is to enforce SSL only for your production environment, thus instead of putting this configuration in your general `application.rb` file, you can set it in your `config/environments/production.rb`.

In case you need to enforce SSL only for specific controllers, you could also just call the force_ssl method in the top of your controller as:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl
  [...your actions..]
end
```

#### My problem & solution through Rails

I wanted to add this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /pt/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/$ /en/ [L,R=301]
```

And finally had to do it in the `config/routes.rb`  config file of rails with

```
get '/', to: redirect { |path_params, req|
"/#{req.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^(?:pt|fr)/).first || 'en'}" }
```

**Any help from the OpenShift team to explain where to put a `.htaccess` for a Ruby cartridge is still very welcome!**

Comment: Great solution thank you very much!!! Do you know how do I force the www. subdomain also?

Comment: Hum, not sure how to enforce www. on OpenShift. You might be interessed to read this though: http://trevorturk.com/2009/11/05/no-www-rack-middleware/

Comment: I'd also appreciate "Any help from the OpenShift team to explain where to put a .htaccess for a Ruby cartridge is still very welcome!"

Comment: @paul-b just found this if it's any use and you've not already seen it: http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2012/09/11/search-engine-friendly-redirects-for-custom-domains-on-openshift-using-a-htaccess-file.html

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution for Ruby 1.9 for OpenShift 2 with steps for terminal:

cd your_ruby_git_project_folder/public/

vi .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

cd ..

git add . -A

git commit -m 'message'

git push

Comment: inspired by http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2012/09/11/2012-09-11-search-engine-friendly-redirects-for-custom-domains-on-openshift-using-a-htaccess-file.markdown.html