# OpenShift and Jekyll Cartridge Force SSL

Tags: ssl, openshift, jekyll

I'm using an application on OpenShift started from the Jekyll Cartridge, but running octopress on top (I suppose that's the same difference).

I would like to automatically redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS. So that it can only be viewed over HTTPS.

I don't see a way to do this with Jekyll served on OpenShift, using the cartridge. I can do it locally, by modifying my config.ru file but that has no effect on OpenShift. Is there a way to force this on my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, I'm not too happy with it as a "solution", but it works so I'm posting it.

The Jekyll cartridge seemed to be using WEBrick as the webserver, and I couldn't get control over it well enough to make it enforce SSL.

Basically I made a new application based on the "Ruby 1.9" cartridge, instead of the Jekyll cartridge. This gave me an apache hosted application. I then had to put use the .htaccess file as suggested by David earlier, in the source (!) folder of my octopress blog:

```
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https  
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

That did the trick. I don't think it's an ideal solution though, so all better solutions are welcome.

Here's everything I did in detail to move from the Jekyll cartridge to the Ruby 1.9 Cartridge:

1. Make a new openshift application, using the Ruby 1.9 Cartridge
2. Clone the new openshift application's git repo to a local folder
3. Copy all the files from the original repository to this new repository
4. Re-generate using Jekyll (rake generate)
5. Add and commit everything
6. Then push to openshift (this should result in a blog working as before)
7. Merge with github repo (git pull )
8. Add github as a remote (and deal with some minor conflicts)

Now I can work in my repo and perform "git push" (to openshift) and "git push ".

To force SSL:

1. Create an .htaccess file in the "source" folder of my octopress blog and re-generate.

Note: Now I have to make sure to do "rake generate" before I push to openshift (although I guess I could automate that on openshift after an update).

Answer (score 1):

If your app is served by apache, you can try to put an .htaccess file at you root, containing :

```
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https  
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

from [openshift kb](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1044-how-to-redirect-traffic-to-https)

Comment: Sounds good, do you happen to know what the "root" is? I've tried putting it into the root of my repo (where you can also find  config.rb, _config.yml etc ... But that seemed to have little effect. I've also put it in "public". I'm probably looking straight over the obvious :|

Comment: try renaming your .htcaccess to .htaccess

Comment: Wow ... djee, what can you say to that ... Need new glasses I guess.

Comment: Hmm sorry, that still doesn't seem to be it. I can still just view the HTTP version. I seem to be not alone though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906010/http-to-https-redirect-on-openshift-rails-app?rq=1 (solution in that post doesn't seem to apply to jekyll though).

Comment: If I produce a 404 on the blog, it exposes its running WEBrick/1.3.1. So from this I conclude it's not actually using apache, which would explain why my .htaccess is not being used. Not sure how much influence I have on this webserver though.